# Decreased accuracy when converting keras code to pytorch

Tags: keras, pytorch

I am a beginner in Pytorch and I am trying to convert a keras code to Pytorch for classification task.
The results are different for me in two modes with the same settings. Accuracy is reduced by 5% and the Loss is increases from 0.2 to 4.5. Can anyone tell me if I converted the code correctly to Pytorch or not? Thank you so much.
IMG_HEIGHT=48 ,IMG_WIDTH=48 , channels=3, num_class=164

```
model = keras.models.Sequential([    
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT,IMG_WIDTH,channels)),
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1),

keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu'),
keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1),

keras.layers.Flatten(),
keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5),

keras.layers.Dense(164, activation='softmax')])
```

pytorch :

```
class convnet(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, num_class):
    super(convnet, self).__init__()
    self.Conv2d_1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 16, (3,3))
    self.relu_1 = nn.ReLU()
    self.Conv2d_2 = nn.Conv2d(16, 32, (3,3))
    self.relu_2 = nn.ReLU()
    self.maxpool_1 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    self.batch_1 = nn.BatchNorm2d(32)

    self.Conv2d_3 = nn.Conv2d(32, 64, (3,3))
    self.relu_3 = nn.ReLU()
    self.Conv2d_4 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, (3,3))
    self.relu_4 = nn.ReLU()
    self.maxpool_2 = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
    self.batch_2 = nn.BatchNorm2d(128)        

    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10368, 1024)  
    self.relu_5 = nn.ReLU()
    self.batch_3 = nn.BatchNorm1d(1024)      
    self.dropout_1 = nn.Dropout(p=0.5)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(1024,num_class)
    self.Softmax_1 = nn.Softmax()

def forward(self, x):

    y = self.Conv2d_1(x)
    y = self.relu_1(y)
    y = self.Conv2d_2(y)
    y = self.relu_2(y)
    y = self.maxpool_1(y)
    y = self.batch_1(y)

    y = self.Conv2d_3(y)
    y = self.relu_3(y)
    y = self.Conv2d_4(y)
    y = self.relu_4(y)
    y = self.maxpool_2(y)
    y = self.batch_2(y)

    y = y.view(y.size(0), -1)
    y = self.fc1(y)
    y = self.relu_5(y)
    y = self.batch_3(y)
    y = self.dropout_1(y)
    y = self.fc2(y)
    y = self.Softmax_1(y)

    return y
```

Comment: what's your loss function?

Comment: You should also specify the dimension for your softmax (at least for good practice): `self.Softmax_1 = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)`.

Comment: @joe32140 in keras code i use categorical_crossentropy and in pytorch i use nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

Comment: @jhso I applied dim=-1 and there was no change in the result.

Comment: For  nn.CrossEntropyLoss, you don't need to use softmax in your forward function. It takes logits as input and will apply softmax internally.

Comment: yes, @joe32140 is correct. You should only apply your softmax in inference.

Comment: @joe32140 I did that and got the result I wanted. Thank you very much both of you.